# Is there some event to determine when DataGrid columns change (i.e. added, removed) in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

Is there some event to determine when DataGrid columns change (i.e. added, removed) in Silverlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well DataGrid.Columns is ObservableCollection, so we can use 
`dataGrid1.Columns.CollectionChanged+=Columns_CollectionChanged;`

But that's kinda weird.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there is no such event on the DataGrid itself. I think I would monitor the datasource which the DataGrid is bound to instead and work from there. Hope this helps.